# What is an AsyncTask (or AsyncResult) and how is it typically used for Android?

Tags: java, android

Can't find much about this concept.  Have already referred to

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncResult.java

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/AsyncResult.html

***Edit:***  I believe the AsyncResult I was referring to was the particular name chosen to hold the result from a generic [asynchronous operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean).  (Background operation that will asynchronously notify the user when it is done.)

It seems the links above are just particular implementations of this concept.
For reference, see these instead:

- [Developer.android.com - AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Developer.android.com - Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: Why do you need that? It isn't of much use and also annotated with `@hide` meaning "not for the general public to use"

Comment: The two links you posted are not at all about the same thing,

Comment: @WorldSEnder, in the version I have seen, it is not annotated hidden

Comment: @ci_ yes i realize this, I am looking for an explanation of the concept or pattern, maybe with an android example

Comment: @tbone, in the first link *you provided* it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background / Theory

**AsyncTask** allows you to run a task on a background thread, while publishing results to the UI thread.

> The user should always able to interact with the app so it is **important**
>   **to avoid blocking the main (UI) thread** with tasks such as
>   downloading content from the web.
>
> This is why we use an **`AsyncTask`**.
>
> It offers a straightforward interface by *wrapping the UI thread message queue and handler that allow you to send and process runnable objects and messages from other threads*.

### Implementation

**AsyncTask** is a generic class.  (It takes **parameterized types** in its constructor.)

It uses these **three generic types:**

**`Params`** - the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.

**`Progress`** - the type of the progress units published during the background computation.

**`Result`** - the type of the result of the background computation.

> Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void:
>
> `private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }`

These three parameters **correspond to three primary functions** you can override in **`AsyncTask`**:

- `doInBackground(Params...)`
- `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`
- `onPostExecute(Result)`

**To execute AsyncTask**

call **`execute()`** with parameters to be sent to the background task.

**What Happens**

1. On main/UI thread, **`onPreExecute()`** is called. (To initialize something in this thread such as show a progress bar on the user interface.)
2. On a background thread, **`doInBackground(Params...)`** is called.  (The parameters are those passed to the Execute function.)

   - Where the long-running task should happen
   - Must override at least `doInBackground()` to use AsyncTask.
   - Call **`publishProgress(Progress...)`** to update a display of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. (e.g. animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.)

     - This causes **`onProgressUpdate()`** to be called.
3. On the background thread, a result is returned from `doInBackground()`.  This triggers the next step.
4. On main/UI thread, **`onPostExecute()`** called with the returned result.

### Examples

Using again the example of the blocking task being to download something from the web,

- **Example A downloads an image** and displays it in an ImageView,
- while **Example B downloads some files**.

### Example A

The `doInBackground()` method downloads the image and stores it in an object of type BitMap.  The `onPostExecute()` method takes the bitmap and places it in the ImageView.

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bitImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bitImage) {
        this.bitImage = bitImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mBmp = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mBmp;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bitImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

### Example B

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

**Example B execution**

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```